# codeigniter database error occurred when updating record

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, record

i have an error

```
Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'Nama_Material_Jasa' in 'field list'

UPDATE `ms_material_jasa` SET `Kode_Kategori_Material_Jasa` = 'KKMJ004', `Nama_Material_Jasa` = 'batuasdf' WHERE `Kode_Kategori_Material_Jasa` = 'KKMJ004'

Filename: C:\wamp\www\QBA\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330
```

and this is my update model

```
function update($getid,$getnama)
{
    $data = array('Kode_Kategori_Material_Jasa' => $getid,'Nama_Material_Jasa' => $getnama);
    $this->db->where('Kode_Kategori_Material_Jasa', $getid);
    $this->db->update('ms_material_jasa', $data); 
}
```

and here is my controller

```
 function ubah()
{
    $getid = $this->input->post('kkmj');
    $getnama = $this->input->post('nmj');
    $data['pesan'] = $getid.' berhasil diubah ! ';
    $data['title'] = 'QB Ubah Kategori Material';

    $this->m_kategorimaterial->update($getid,$getnama);
    //echo $getid.$getnama; //it returns KKMJ005newVal , like i want

    $this->load->view('head',$data);
    $this->load->view('v/vkategorimaterial',$data);

}
```

when i echo `$getid` and `$getnama` variable, it returns `KKMJ005Newval` so no problem on controller, i believe it has something to do with the models,

how do i resolve this ?

the table name is `ms_kategori_material` and it has 2 field, `Kode_Kategori_Material_Jasa` and `Nama_Material_Jasa`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said your table name is `ms_kategori_material`, but your code reads

```
$this->db->update('ms_material_jasa', $data);
```

So try changing it to:

```
$this->db->update('ms_kategori_material', $data);
```